# Retrieving everything before the comma

Tags: python

I know that my variable will store something like:

```
x = '(2,)'
x = '(5,)'
```

How can i extract only the number (before the comma and remove brackets ) and store as x

so overall

x = 2

or x = 5

EDIT: Sorry for my very bad programming language, it was a tuple not a string, thank you for the help.

Comment: where did you variable come from? why is it stored in this odd way initially? It's probably better to parse it differently upstream rather than fix it now

Comment: @Chris_Rands It is obtained from an SQL statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code removes all leading and trailing parentheses as well as commas:

```
x.strip('(),')
```

If you also want to convert the result to an integer, use:

```
int(x.strip('(),'))
```

However, it seems that your `x` is not a string but really a Python tuple:

```
x = (2,)
```

In that case, simply use:

```
x[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, please see ammended - sorry I forgot the brackets encapsulating it!

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
y = x[:x.find(',')]
```

After OP edited question:

```
y = x[x.find('(')+1:x.find(',')]
```

Example of execution (`jupyter`):

```
x = '(5,)'

y = x[x.find('(')+1:x.find(',')]

y
Out[24]: '5'
```

Comment: Caveat! This will blindly remove the latest digit in case your input string does not end with ",". That is, `x='23'` leads to `y='2'`. This might not happen with your input right now, but in case it does, it will be very surprising and hard to debug.

Comment: @vog Yes, I know about it. But OP wrote `How can i extract only the number (before the comma) `. I assume, that input string will contain comma.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, please see ammended - sorry I forgot the brackets encapsulating it! Yes, at the moment there is always a comma

Comment: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: @Lottie T Could you provide input data on which you get AttributeError?

Comment: @Lottie T It seems that your question is stated wrongly. Your input is not a string but a Python tuple. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46787229/19163

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
import re
regex = r"(\d*)\,"
test_str = "10,"
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str)
x = int(matches[0]) # 10
```

[Try online here](http://tpcg.io/gO72QA)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, please see ammended - sorry I forgot the brackets encapsulating it!